# html 5 left menu positioning

Tags: html

Can anyone help on this positioning issue? I would like the left menu to be positioned vertically without any blank space. You can see from  [the website](http://bricabrac.tekcities.com/)

Also the whole code below if you can help from there, thanks

html **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0064)http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web site</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>

</style>

<!-- Tell IE we are using html5 + CSS -->
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="site"> 
        <h1>WEBSITE</h1>
    </header>


    <article>  
        <header>
            <h2>This is the article header</h2>
            <time datetime="25-11-2010" pubdate="">25th November 2010</time>
        </header>
        <section id="abstract">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et orci sed neque tincidunt dictum nec at lacus. Fusce feugiat sagittis ligula ac aliquam. Integer ut sodales justo. Etiam ultrices cursus iaculis. Suspendisse bibendum. </p>
        </section>
        <section id="main">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac velit mauris. Nulla cursus pretium dapibus. Fusce at faucibus mi. Etiam ac nisi condimentum quam vulputate euismod. Nunc viverra consectetur tempor. Praesent rutrum diam in leo lacinia sit amet volutpat leo tempus. Donec sodales, velit et viverra imperdiet, velit leo placerat libero, fringilla scelerisque justo sapien sit amet sapien. Donec blandit tellus at mi hendrerit hendrerit. Sed suscipit sagittis sodales. Etiam sagittis, tortor quis sagittis laoreet, erat nibh mollis sem, ut tristique felis augue non metus. </p>
            <p>Etiam in gravida mi. Maecenas placerat, justo vel gravida egestas, odio sem dictum justo, eget volutpat massa augue in augue. Sed tempus sem a nulla eleifend aliquet aliquet diam pharetra. Proin sit amet imperdiet est. Cras vitae felis in nulla tristique porttitor ut sit amet neque. Quisque sed nisi quam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam dignissim augue odio. Nam sit amet ipsum arcu, id rutrum felis. Phasellus velit mauris, dictum eget tincidunt eget, condimentum eget risus. Proin nibh nulla, sagittis et feugiat in, luctus quis velit. Aenean lobortis mi ut odio accumsan adipiscing. Nulla quis ipsum magna. Suspendisse auctor mauris eu mi cursus ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas gravida vulputate leo, consectetur porta sem euismod nec. Donec et dolor lectus, vel cursus massa. Morbi eu dictum arcu. Fusce luctus porttitor neque, sed eleifend orci tristique convallis. </p>
        </section>
    </article>

   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Service</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

    <footer> 
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Contact</h4>
            <adress>
                <p><a href="http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html#">Janet Griffith</a> from Public Relations</p>
                <p><a href="http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html#">Jil Sanders</a>, webmaster</p>

        </adress></div>
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Sites of interest</h4>
            <aside>
                <p><a href="http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html#">Site A</a></p>
                <p><a href="http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html#">Another one</a></p>
            </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Legal stuff</h4>
            <p>Copyright</p>
            <p>Terms of Service</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    </div>


</body></html>
```

style sheet **style.css**

```
/* reset the margin and padding and tell the browser to render all HTML5 section tags as block. ->*/
*       {margin:0px; padding:0px;}

header, hgroup, footer, section, aside, article, figcaption, figure, nav {
    display: block;
}
/* <- reset the margin and padding and tell the browser to render all HTML5 section tags as block.*/

/*The CSS for the basic layout looks like follows. First, by wrapping all other content with the wrapper div we restrict the overall page width to 90% of the browser and leave a little bit of extra margin to the top-border. In addition, the margin-left / margin-right is set to auto meaning our content will always be centered inside the browser.*/

/*Open the code in a new window and resize it to see how the width adapts! First, in our CSS section we introduce a little bit of padding between the browser window and the content. Then, we add some color to the header and footer to actually see them.*/

/* The wrapper centers the rest of the content */
div#wrapper {width:90%; margin: 10px auto;}

/* add some color to distinguish the three sections of the document: header, the main section and the footer. */
/* Next, we set explicitly the height of the header to 80 pixels, add some background color and padding. The margin values introduce top and bottom spacing of 10px. In addition all content will be centered with text-align:center. */
header#site {
    height:80px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#0033FF;
    margin:10px 0px;
    text-align:center;
}
/*Finally, the  footer. Usually has a small font-size which is set in our example to 0.8 units of the standard size. Again, some background color. The clear:both make sure that the footer actually is displayed below the main article; it explictly tells the browser that no floating elements are allowed on both sides of the footer.*/
footer {
    font-size:0.8em;
    clear:both;}

footer .col {
    width:30%;
    margin:1% 1.1%;
    padding:2px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#F63;
    float:left;
}


nav {
    background-color:#0033FF;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;}


nav ul {
    list-style:none;}

nav ul li {
    float:left;}

nav ul li a {  
    display: block;  
    background-color:#CCC;
    margin-right: 20px;  
    width: 110px;  
    line-height:1.5em;  
    text-align: center;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    color: #000;  
}  

nav ul li a:hover {  
        color: #fff;  
        background-color:#39C;
}  

/*The actual trick of aligning both the main article and the navigation horizontally on the same line is done with float:left; while making sure that both fill the full available width. Note that although the sum of the article + nav layer adds up to 100%, the padding introduced for the body actually reduces the overall width to 90% of the browser window.*/

/*The CSS for the article tag. Here we have to make sure that we leave some space for the advertising, so we set its width to 80%. In addition, in order to prevent that the ads are being pushed below the main article, we set  float:left.*/

article {
    background-color:#0066FF;
    float:left;
    width:69%;
    margin-right:10px;
  margin-left:31%;
}

article header {
    background-color:#F90;
    padding:15px;
}

section#abstract {
    font-size:1.09em;
    font-style:italic;
    margin:10px 0px;
    text-align:justify;
    padding:5px 80px;
}

section#main {
    font-size:1em;
    padding:20px;
    text-align:justify;
}
/*
section#main{
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;     
}
*/
/* On the right border we place the ads. This is done with the aside tag indicating only remotely related content to the actual article. Each ad has a specific height and width. The overall width together with the main article adds up to 98% (80% + 18%). This is necessary because we have to take into account the 10px margin-right of the article. float:left makes sure the ads are really on the same height as the main article (not below). */
.ads {
    height:100%;
    width:30%;
    background-color:#0033FF;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    float:left; 
    }

.ads p:first-child {
    padding:15px; 
    font-size:2em;}

.ads p:last-child {
    padding-left:15px; 
    font-size:1em;color:#CCC;}
```

I would like this to look like my current web site

http://multiskillz.tekcities.com

Comment: I'm not sure I got your question. The 2 sites are pretty distinct from each other.

Comment: I would like to keep the same layout in the 2 sites or something very similar. --- I am yet not an expert in using stackoverflow, it seems someone said I haven't done any researches, he or she can look at the style sheet file I provided and will see that comments have been moved to place in the code I need to understand and I did spend a day on this, the links to the original layout will show something a bit different, so to say that I made efforts to understand before asking but I am not a designer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
nav {
    background-color:#0033FF;
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:100%;}

article {
    background-color:#0066FF;
    float:right;
    width:69%;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, just perfect! I will not ask any further question as I'll keep this basic but functional design and I am not likely to go with sophisticated stuff. I'll link this page and answers from my website. Thanks!

Comment: Please upvote or select answer as best answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I didn't notice the mark-up vote...until you tell me to choose best answer (I am quite new on this site).I give it as you were quick in providing a working script but everyone else does deserve this to. I'm frustrated about not being able to rate others. I should have other related but I will keep subjects distinct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove `float:left` from `article`, and make it `float:right`

make `nav float:left`

add `clear:both` after

http://jsfiddle.net/feitla/hFGbb/

Comment: I tried to implement these fix but it's not changing anything as intended. However, the link to your page, is showing exactly what I want. So, if I have time, I'll see what is not working

Comment: That is because of the order of your HTML. Move the nav element BEFORE the article element if you want them to float right.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jsfiddle showing an example of my solution... http://jsfiddle.net/zfn7L/

So first as the others said, change the article to be `float: right`, remove the `margin-left: 31%`, and remove the float styling for the `li` elements. Then move the nav inside the article, remove all the positioning/sizing for it, and add the following:

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 110px; /* Takes into account the header */
  width: 29%;
}
```

Last, just add `position: relative` to `div#wrapper` so that the absolute positioning of the nav can be based off that larger container, and you should be good to go!

Comment: hi, it does the positioning job with a few adjustments. thanks, if you don't mind, I'll link this page to question about the design I chose to implement and code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the structure :

**HTML**

```
<header></header>
<section>
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="side"></div>

   <div style="clear: right;"></div>
</section>
<footer></footer>
```

This is very important that you should add `float` to your side or content, depending on your case.

Checkout this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/EsDcX/

Comment: Hi, you're helping with div when I'm trying to do an entire html5 website. So, I haven't implemented your fix. Still, thanks for your help

Comment: @Pluto What do you mean variable heights?? While website must has a dynamic height.

Comment: Hi Aldi, I am using the positioning you provided through jsfiddle. I will raise the height issue in another question the same way I did here, I will copy paste the script with your adjustments and a reference to the question on this page. If you can help there as well I will give you a vote even if you do it later because you have already answered something that works nice here and I gave the only vote to Aayushi.thanks [link to the new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767128/html-5-positionning-with-or-without-div)