# html 5 positionning with or without div

Tags: css, html

I would like to know if for the demo index page of [this site url](http://bricabrac.tekcities.com/), I can prevent the text from overflowing or let say use optional scrolling bar when the text goes over the bottom of the blue box? I would like the layout to be similar to [this 'production' site](http://multiskillz.tekcities.com/) (with server stats visits).

Can I do this using html 5? Should I include div so to limit text overflow under a certain screen resolution. Please find the html and style sheet code used (thanks for the author of this design and also Aayushi Jain who has help me with a few style sheet adjustments from another question here on this site).

style sheet

```
 html { 
   overflow-y: scroll; } 

 div#wrapper {
   width:90%; 
   margin: 10px auto; 
   position: relative;}

 header#site {
     height:80px;
     padding:10px;
     background-color:#0033FF;
     margin:10px 0px;
     text-align:center; } 

 footer {
     font-size:0.8em;
     clear:both;}

 footer .col {
     width:30%;
     margin:1% 1.1%;
     padding:2px;
     height:100px;
     background-color:#F63;
     float:left; }


 nav {
     background-color:#0033FF;
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     top: 110px;
     width: 29%; }


 nav ul {
     list-style:none;}


 nav ul li a {  
     display: block;  
     background-color:#CCC;
     margin-right: 20px;  
     width: 110px;  
     line-height:1.5em;  
     text-align: center;  
     text-decoration: none;  
     color: #000;   }  

 nav ul li a:hover {  
         color: #fff;  
         background-color:#39C; }  

 article {
     background-color:#0066FF;
     float:right;
     width:69%;
     margin-right:10px;
     height:50%;
     overflow-y:scroll;
      }

 article header {
     background-color:#F90;
     padding:15px; }

 section#abstract {
     font-size:1.09em;
     font-style:italic;
     margin:10px 0px;
     text-align:justify;
     padding:5px 80px; }

section#main {
     font-size:1em;
     padding:20px;
     text-align:justify;  
     float: left;   
     margin: 0;   
     padding: 0;   
     display: inline; }

 .ads {
     height:50%;
     width:30%;
     background-color:#0033FF;
     margin-bottom:1%;
     float:left;}

 .ads p:first-child {
     padding:15px; 
     font-size:2em;}

 .ads p:last-child {
     padding-left:15px; 
     font-size:1em;color:#CCC;}
```

the html file

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0064)http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Web site</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>

</style>

<!-- Tell IE we are using html5 + CSS -->
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header id="site"> 
        <h1>WEBSITE</h1>
    </header>

    <article>  
        <header>
            <h2>This is the article header</h2>
            <time datetime="25-11-2010" pubdate="">25th November 2010</time>
        </header>
        <section id="abstract">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam et orci sed neque tincidunt dictum nec at lacus. Fusce feugiat sagittis ligula ac aliquam. Integer ut sodales justo. Etiam ultrices cursus iaculis. Suspendisse bibendum. </p>
        </section>
        <section id="main">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ac velit mauris. Nulla cursus pretium dapibus. Fusce at faucibus mi. Etiam ac nisi condimentum quam vulputate euismod. Nunc viverra consectetur tempor. Praesent rutrum diam in leo lacinia sit amet volutpat leo tempus. Donec sodales, velit et viverra imperdiet, velit leo placerat libero, fringilla scelerisque justo sapien sit amet sapien. Donec blandit tellus at mi hendrerit hendrerit. Sed suscipit sagittis sodales. Etiam sagittis, tortor quis sagittis laoreet, erat nibh mollis sem, ut tristique felis augue non metus. </p>
            <p>Etiam in gravida mi. Maecenas placerat, justo vel gravida egestas, odio sem dictum justo, eget volutpat massa augue in augue. Sed tempus sem a nulla eleifend aliquet aliquet diam pharetra. Proin sit amet imperdiet est. Cras vitae felis in nulla tristique porttitor ut sit amet neque. Quisque sed nisi quam. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam dignissim augue odio. Nam sit amet ipsum arcu, id rutrum felis. Phasellus velit mauris, dictum eget tincidunt eget, condimentum eget risus. Proin nibh nulla, sagittis et feugiat in, luctus quis velit. Aenean lobortis mi ut odio accumsan adipiscing. Nulla quis ipsum magna. Suspendisse auctor mauris eu mi cursus ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas gravida vulputate leo, consectetur porta sem euismod nec. Donec et dolor lectus, vel cursus massa. Morbi eu dictum arcu. Fusce luctus porttitor neque, sed eleifend orci tristique convallis. </p>
        </section>
    </article>

   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>About</li>
      <li>Service</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

    <footer> 
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Contact</h4>
            <adress>
                <p><a href="http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html#">Janet Griffith</a> from Public Relations</p>
                <p><a href="http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html#">Jil Sanders</a>, webmaster</p>

        </adress></div>
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Sites of interest</h4>
            <aside>
                <p><a href="http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html#">Site A</a></p>
                <p><a href="http://toytic.com/class/examples/e808_html5_Header2NavAside.html#">Another one</a></p>
            </aside>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h4>Legal stuff</h4>
            <p>Copyright</p>
            <p>Terms of Service</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    </div>


</body></html>
```

thanks

Pascal

Comment: brother your question is related to css

Comment: what is difference of HTML5 Positioning and HTML4 Positioning.

Comment: From my understanding of html5, tags such as div could be replaced with section, headers, footers... but it seems properties applicable to div are not applicable to html 5 tags such as overflow:auto

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the scroll bar then use `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto`.

Now if you want the header part to be static then put your section main and abstract in a div and make its `height: 500px (or something you want)` but make it fix and then use `overflow: hidden` in the newly mad div if you don't want to show the overflow part or use `overflow: auto` if you want to show the overflow part but not the scroll bar.